# TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, gdal, numpy

I am trying python for the first time. I have a raster layer of Type Float32, and another raster output of Type Integer created from this raster layer outside the python code. I want to scan every column wise, and pick up the Float raster minimum value location within a 5 neighbourhood of Integer raster value of 1 in every column and assign the value 1 at this minimum value location and all other pixels as Null.

I am getting the Type Error : 'int' object does not support item assignment

I am giving the python code below:

```
new_array = [ [0 for i in range(band.XSize)] for j in range(band.YSize)]

for i, item in enumerate(myarray1):
    for j, element in enumerate(item):
        if (myarray2[i][j] == 1):
            if myarray1[i][j] < myarray1[i-2][j]:
                new_array[i-2][j] = -999
                if myarray1[i][j] < myarray1[i-1][j]:
                    new_array[i-1][j] = -999
                    if myarray1[i][j] < myarray1[i+1][j]:
                        if myarray1[i][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i][j] = 1                
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                    else:
                        if myarray1[i+1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i+1][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                else:
                    if myarray1[i-1][j] < myarray1[i+1][j]:
                        if myarray1[i-1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i-1][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                    else:
                        if myarray1[i+1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i+1][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
            else:
                if myarray1[i-2][j] < myarray1[i-1][j]:
                    if myarray1[i-2][j] < myarray1[i+1][j]:
                        if myarray1[i-2][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            #new_array[i-2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                    else:
                        if myarray1[i+1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i+1][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                else:
                    if myarray1[i-1][j] < myarray1[i+1][j]:
                        if myarray1[i-1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i-1] = 1
                            #new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                    else:
                        if myarray1[i+1][j] < myarray1[i+2][j]:
                            new_array[i+1] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
                        else:
                            new_array[i+2][j] = 1
                            new_array[i][j] = -999
        else:
            new_array[i][j] = -999
```

Comment: At what line are you getting this error?

Comment: You do not seem to be using QGIS so I removed the tag for that and added one for GDAL that you do appear to be using.  Please try to provide a [code snippet](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4312/writing-code-snippets-to-get-quicker-answers) rather than your full code.

Comment: I am getting the error at the line 92 - corresponding to the line:new_array[i][j] = -999

Comment: This looks like a simple typo in the Python code, on the line `new_array[i-1] = 1` (and any similar ones), where you accidentally change your array's structure, not at all related to GIS aspects of your code.

Comment: You are missing the whole point of using `numpy` by looping through each cell. Search for rolling window using `numpy`

Comment: @Dan Getz - Thank you very much for showing the mistake. Can you please suggest solution for this line! Best regards

Comment: @Marcelo Villa - Thank you for the guidance to learn more. I have just started writing python code for my simple tasks. I have just started learning the basics. Best regards

Comment: @Dan Getz - I am really sorry. I understood your point, now only. It's a simply typo error. Thank you so much.